# Angular - extending $resource subobject with custom methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

In most cases the result of `<custom-resource>.query()` method is an array, which can be easily extended with some methods (business logics) with the following (factory) code:

```
var Data = $resource('http://..');
Data.prototype.foo = function() {return ...};
```

this is perfect for using with ng-repeat / ng-class, like so:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in responseData" ng-class="{warning: item.foo()}">..</tr>
```

My problem is that **every list response is encapsulated** in an object which, besides the actual list, has some meta-properties (sorting info etc), so the final object returned is like this:

```
{ order_field: "name", items: [{..}, {..},{..}] }
```

Now, how do I make the same thing as previously with ng-repeat/ng-class?

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in responseData.items" ng-class="????">..</tr>
```

the previous method won't work as the "foo" method is defined on `responseData` and NOT on `item` object

Is there any way to directly extend the base class used for instantiating objects on the list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I've found that problem before, and the solution seems to be `transformResponse`, as John Ledbetter says in the other answer.

Anyway, **if you need to keep the entire object**, and also having the array in 'items' filled with instances of the resource, you might be able to do it with the following trick:

Taking the example from John's answer, and modifying it a bit:

```
angular.module('foo')

  .factory('Post', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    var Post = $resource('/api/posts/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: false, // <- not returning an array
        transformResponse: function(data, header) {
          var wrapped = angular.fromJson(data);
          angular.forEach(wrapped.items, function(item, idx) {
             wrapped.items[idx] = new Post(item); //<-- replace each item with an instance of the resource object
          });
          return wrapped;
        }
      }
    });

    Post.prototype.foo = function() { /* ... */ };

    return Post;
  }]);
```

Comment: I think this is a solid solution.  It doesn't feel _perfect_ to me, but it's the best I've seen :)

Answer (score 9):

If you're using angular-resource 1.1.5 (which as far as I can tell actually works fine with angular 1.0.7), there is a `transformResponse` option you can specify when overriding `$resource` methods:

```
angular.module('foo')
  .factory('Post', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    var Post = $resource('/api/posts/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
      query: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true,
        transformResponse: function(data, header) {
          var wrapped = angular.fromJson(data);
          return wrapped.items;
        }
      }
    });

    Post.prototype.foo = function() { /* ... */ };

    return Post;
  }]);
```

If you do this, you no longer have to manually pull the items out of the wrapped response, and each item will be an instance of `Post` that has access to the `.foo` method.  You can just write:

```
<tr ng-repeat="post in posts" ng-class="{warning: post.foo()}">..</tr>
```

The downside to this is that you lose access to any of the outer fields in your response that aren't inside items.  I'm still struggling to figure out a way to preserve that metadata.

Comment: thanks, but this is not really what I'm looking for. As I'm writing both angular-js frontend and C#-backend, I could simply avoid wrapping the list in the object, but the point is I need that metadata too.

Comment: @migajek I understand, I'm in the same situation -- I'd like to be able to support paging/sorting with my API without having to manually 'unbox' all the resources.  Be interested to see if there are any good answers to this.

Comment: I add the metadata back by adding a closure variable 
function(){
    var meta = {}; 
    var Product = $resource = {tranformResponse : function(data)   {
        meta.prop = data.prop;}
    }
    Product._meta = meta;
    return product;
}

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I just ran into this issue myself. gargc's solution is the right approach, but there is an improvement. `transformResponse` accepts an array that gets passed to the `$http` service. Rather than completely replace the transform function, you can append your transform to the defaults to just make the updates you need:

```
angular.module('foo')
    .factory('Post', function ($resource, $http) {
        var Post = $resource('/api/posts/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: false,
                transformResponse: $http.defaults.transformResponse.concat(function(data, header) {
                    angular.forEach(data.items, function(item, idx) {
                        data.items[idx] = new Post(item);
                    });
                    return data;
                })
            }
        });

        Post.prototype.foo = function() { /* ... */ };

        return Post;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the metadata in a header. I always put paging data there.  That way your query will still return an array, which I believe is a good thing. Queries should return arrays of data, not single data.