# Can anyone explain how to use this angular js custom resource method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Now can anyone explain that how I can use these custom methods? I know about the basic methods of resource and how to use them but this thing is confusing.

```
app.factory('ResouceService', ['$resource', '$window',

    function($resource, $window) {

        return {
            request: function($url) {
                return $resource($url + ':id', {}, {
                    query: {
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {},
                        isArray: false
                    },
                    get: {
                        method: 'GET'
                    },
                    remove: {
                        method: 'DELETE'
                    },
                    edit: {
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {},
                        isArray: false
                    },
                    add: {
                        method: 'PUT',
                        data: {},
                        isArray: false
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }
]);
```

Comment: you should go here and check this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: i have checked out there already but not found very helpful.

Comment: Go to this..You will be able to... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138147/add-a-custom-function-on-angular-resource

Comment: No offense but i have put my question here after lot of search including the above mentioned link.
my question is that how can i use resource operations or you can say how can i send data in restful way by these custom actions.

Answer (score 0):

Use your factory method in your controller

```
app.controller('customerController', function($scope, ResouceService) {
                $scope.myMethods = ResouceService;
            });
```

Comment: Thank you i know this...but what i meant by above question is that further how can i send data to backend(php) or in which way can i access those function.