# Extending $resource object removes prototype from Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects, angularjs-resource

Here is the code that I have right now:

```
// Factory
angular.factory('Student', function() {
    var defaults = {
        StudentId: null
    };

    var Student = function(params) {
        angular.extend(this, angular.copy(defaults), params);
    };

    // Prototype function for Student
    Student.prototype.hasStudentId = function() {
        return this.StudentId != null;
    };
});

// Service
angular.service('StudentService', ['Student', '$resource', function(Student, $resource) {
    var service = {};

    service.student = $resource('student/:studentId'. {} { load: {method: 'GET'} });

    service.loadStudent = function(studentId) {
        var currentStudent = service.student.load(studentId); // HTTP call

        currentStudent.$promise.then(function() {
            // I expect the object currentStudent would have hasStudentId() prototype function, but it's not
            angular.extend(currentStudent, new Student(currentStudent));

            // However, if I use 'new' keyword, studentObj has prototype hasStudentId() function
            var studentObj = new Student(currentStudent);
        });
    };

    return service;
}]);
```

As you see, after I extend `currentStudent` object, currentStudent doesn't have the prototype function `hasStudentId()`.  However, if I use `new Student(currentStudent)`, it has the prototype function properly.

Does Angular.extend ignore `prototype` functions?

Currently, `currentStudent` object only has the `$resource`'s prototype functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) `angular.extend` only copies *own* enumerable properties. Prototype properties may be enumerable but they do not belong to the object itself and, therefore, do not qualify as *own*. MDN has an article on this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties).

Comment: What should I use then instead of angular.extend?

Comment: Why don't you enrich your $resource directly with the needed functionality?

Comment: The easiest way is to just define prototype-functions to the $resource, in this question you'll find an answer with an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138147/add-a-custom-function-on-angular-resource