# AngularJS, $http and transformResponse

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm getting a strange behaviour with AngularJS's $http and not really understanding how transformResponse works (the docs are a bit light on this one).

```
    WebAssets.get = function () {
        return $http.get('/api/webassets/list', {
            transformResponse: [function (data, headersGetter) {
                // not sure what to do here?!
                return data;
            }].concat($http.defaults.transformResponse) // presume this isn't needed, added for clarity
        }).then(function (response) {
            return new WebAssets(response.data);
        });
    };
```

The api returns an array of objects:

```
[{"webasset_name": "...", "application_id": "...", "etc": "..."}, ... ]
```

But when transformResponse has done it's evil business the data has transformed into an indexed object:

```
{"0":{"webasset_name":"...","application_id":"...", "etc": "..."}, "1":....}
```

I want to keep the original data structure (an array of objects).

Comment: You might want to have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134401/angular-extending-resource-subobject-with-custom-methods

Comment: They are using $resource, I'm using $http

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get angular to not convert your data into an object you need to override the behavior of the default $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse. It is actually an array of transformers.
You could just set it to be empty: `$http.defaults.transformResponse = [];`
Here is an example transformer I have used to convert 64-bit long ints to strings:

```
function longsToStrings(response) {
    //console.log("transforming response");
    var numbers = /("[^"]*":\s*)(\d{15,})([,}])/g;
    var newResponse = response.replace(numbers, "$1\"$2\"$3");
    return newResponse;
}
```

To add a transformer to the default list, say ahead of the JSON deserializer, you can do this:

```
$http.defaults.transformResponse.unshift(longsToStrings);
```

Answer (score 3):

Resource 0: "f" 1: "a" 2: "l" 3: "s" 4: "e"
This finally worked for me:

```
   transformResponse: function (data, headersGetter) {
    return { isCorrect: angular.fromJson(data) }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using resource query method

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6314

Comment: I think what you need to do is informing the $http that you are returning array instead of an object

Comment: Can you extend your answer with some example code? It's always clearer to see code and a description. You can [edit] your answer. By the way, why did you create two accounts?