# AngularJS http.get verify valid json

Tags: json, angularjs, verify

When getting a json from a URL I only want to work with it, when the data is valid.

my approach so far by using [JSON](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js):

```
$http.get(
            'data/mydata.json'
                + "?rand=" + Math.random() * 10000,
            {cache: false}
        )
            .then(function (result) {

                try {
                    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.data)); // verify that json is valid
                    console.log(jsonObject)

                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log(e) // gets called when parse didn't work
                }


            })
```

However before I can do the parsing, angular already fails itself

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at fromJson (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:908:14)
>       at $HttpProvider.defaults.defaults.transformResponse (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:5735:18)
>       at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:5710:12
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at forEach (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:224:11)
>       at transformData (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:5709:3)
>       at transformResponse (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:6328:17)
>       at wrappedCallback (http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:9106:81)
>       at http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js:9192:26 angular.js:7861

How can I prevent angular from throwing this error or how else should I handle verifying the JSON ?

**UPDATE: Solution:**

```
$http.get(
// url:
'data/mydata.json'
    + "?rand=" + Math.random() * 10000

,

// config:
{
    cache: false,
    transformResponse: function (data, headersGetter) {
        try {
            var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data); // verify that json is valid
            return jsonObject;
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log("did not receive a valid Json: " + e)
        }
        return {};
    }
}
)
```

Comment: Its good story but can you please post your `result.data`? or better Plunker

Comment: i have the same issue. it started happening on one of the values being returned. the question is why did the json become invalid? shouldn't the server encode it properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override `transformResponse` in $http. Check this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147126/angularjs-http-and-transformresponse).

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing, and *transformResponse* does the job, BUT, I dont like using transformResponse everytime i use $http.get() or even overriding it because some $http.get() will be json and some not.

So, here is my solution:

```
myApp.factory('httpHandler', function($http, $q) {            
  function createValidJsonRequest(httpRequest) {
    return {
      errorMessage: function (errorMessage) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        httpRequest
          .success(function (response) {
            if (response != undefined && typeof response == "object"){
                deferred.resolve(response);
            } else {
                alert(errorMessage + ": Result is not JSON type");
            }
          })
          .error(function(data) {
            deferred.reject(data);
            alert(errorMessage + ": Server Error");
          });

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  }

  return {
    getJSON: function() {
      return createValidJsonRequest($http.get.apply(null, arguments));
    },
    postJSON: function() {
      return createValidJsonRequest($http.post.apply(null, arguments));
    }
  }
});


myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, httpHandler) {
  // Option 1
  httpHandler.getJSON(URL_USERS)
    .errorMessage("MainCtrl -> Users")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.users = response.users;
    });


  // Option 2 with catch
  httpHandler.getJSON(URL_NEWS)
    .errorMessage("MainCtrl -> News")
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.news = response.news;
    })
    .catch(function(result){
      // do something in case of error
    });


  // Option 3 with POST and data
  httpHandler.postJSON(URL_SAVE_NEWS, { ... })
    .errorMessage("MainCtrl -> addNews")
    .then(function(response) {
         $scope.news.push(response.new);
    });

});
```