# Transforming Requests and Responses in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, http

What does Transforms do in angularjs `http` serivce. Here is how it is explained in documentation with the example below for custom transformation.

> Both requests and responses can be transformed using transformation
>   functions: transformRequest and transformResponse. These properties
>   can be a single function that returns the transformed value
>   (function(data, headersGetter, status)) or an array of such
>   transformation functions, which allows you to push or unshift a new
>   transformation function into the transformation chain

```
function appendTransform(defaults, transform) {

// We can't guarantee that the default transformation is an array
  defaults = angular.isArray(defaults) ? defaults : [defaults];

  // Append the new transformation to the defaults
  return defaults.concat(transform);
}

$http({
  url: '...',
  method: 'GET',
  transformResponse: appendTransform($http.defaults.transformResponse, function(value) {
    return doTransform(value);
  })
});
```

What transform will do ? It is not clearing to me from documentation can some Explain ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS, $http and transformResponse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147126/angularjs-http-and-transformresponse)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out. This should give you a picture of how to use and why it is there as one of the $http's services

[transforming your response using services.transformer.ApiResponse](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-transformresponse)

so you can re-formulate the function's JSON.parse(data) to get what you want your response to have!