# How to add prototypal methods to an angular $resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototype

I'd like to get objects from a server, something like:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
```

I'd like `User` instances to all have certain methods to calculate derived data, without the server having to return it. For example, say for:

```
var aUser = User.get({userId: 43});
```

The server returns something like:

```
{id: 43, name: "Bob", alertTimestamp: 1447365544}
```

I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
if (aUser.alertTimePassed()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Is there a clean way to do this short of something like this, which seems hacky?

```
var alertTimePassed = function () {
    var now = (new Date()).getTime() / 1000;
    return now >= this.alertTimestamp;
};
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId: '@id'}, {
    get: {
        method: "GET", url: '/user/:userId',
        transformResponse: [angular.fromJson, function (obj) {
            obj.alertTimePassed = alertTimePassed;
        }]
    }
});
```

Comment: There are similar questions and answers out there already.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17134401/angular-extending-resource-subobject-with-custom-methods|
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138147/add-a-custom-function-on-angular-resource

Answer (score 0):

If you create your $resource using a factory you can modify the $resource object before returning it from the factory.

```
app.factory('User', function ($resource) {
    var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId: '@id'});

    // add any methods here using prototype
    User.prototype.alertTimePassed = function() {
        // do stuff
    };

    return User;
});
```